# subequations customize arabic numbering in aligned environment

Tags: subequations

i've a rather simple problem for the experts out there! :)

using subequations, it automatically enumerates the subequations in alphabetic order.

is there a way to obtain instead an arabic-enumeration? like

> Eq:  ...        (1)
>
> Eq:  ...        (2)
>
> Eq:  ...        (3.1)
>
> Eq:  ...        (3.2)
>
> Eq:  ...        (4)

... and so on

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside]{article}    
\usepackage{chadstyle} % Loads my formatting 
\usepackage{url} 
\usepackage{hyperref} 
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage{amsthm, etoolbox} 
\usepackage[title,titletoc]{appendix} 
\usepackage{pdflscape} 
\usepackage{mathtools} 
\usepackage{multirow} 
\usepackage{tabularx} 
\usepackage{placeins} % rotating Tables 
\usepackage{rotating} % coloring table columns and rows 
\usepackage{colortbl}

\newcolumntype{a}{>{\columncolor[gray]{.8}}c} 
\newcolumntype{b}{>{\columncolor{white}}c}

\patchcmd{\subequations}{\def\theequation{\theparentequation\alph{equation}}}% 
{\def\theequation{\theparentequation.\arabic{equation}}}{}{}

%some shortcut commands ....

\begin{document}

\section{Model}

\begin{subequations} 
\begin{align} Y_m &= X P_m^{-\sigma_x} \label{eq:Demand_Yg} \\ 
Y_s &= X P_s^{-\sigma_x} \label{eq:Demand_Ys} 
\end{align} 
\end{subequations}

\end{document}
```

Would it be possible to embed the patch within this chadstyle package? As you see, I've already put in the beginning. Thanks!

```
%  chadstyle.sty   Chad Jones, 5/1/08
%
%  Chad's style file for nice paper format.
%  Various ideas for this style are taken from
%    -- Matthias Doepke and Michele Tertilt
%    -- Tony Roberts

\special{papersize=8.5in,11in}
%\usepackage{palatino,amssymb,amsfonts,amsmath,latexsym,setspace}
\usepackage{utopia,amssymb,amsfonts,latexsym,setspace}

\usepackage{amsthm, etoolbox}
\patchcmd\subequations
{\theparentequation\alph{equation}}
{\subequationsformat}
{}{}

\newcommand{\subequationsformat}{\theparentequation.\arabic{equation}}

\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[longnamesfirst]{natbib}


% example file to change the style of LaTeX
% Tony Roberts May 2004
% first colour for latex or pdflatex
\ifx\pdfoutput\@undefined\usepackage[usenames,dvips]{color}
\else\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
% and fix pdf colour problems
\IfFileExists{pdfcolmk.sty}{\usepackage{pdfcolmk}}{} 
\fi

% Chad's colors:
% See http://web.njit.edu/~kevin/rgb.txt.html for possibilities
\definecolor{ChadDarkBlue}{rgb}{.1,0,.2}  
\definecolor{ChadBlue}{rgb}{.1,.1,.5}  
\definecolor{ChadRoyal}{rgb}{.2,.2,.8}  
%\definecolor{ChadGreen}{rgb}{0,.35,.1}
%\definecolor{ChadGreen}{rgb}{0,.5,.25}  % Too bright
%\definecolor{ChadGreen}{rgb}{0,.4,.2}    % Still too bright
\definecolor{ChadGreen}{rgb}{0,.4,0}    % Dark Green
%\definecolor{ChadRed}{rgb}{.8,.1,.2}    % Too bright
\definecolor{ChadRed}{rgb}{.5,0,.5}  % purple

%%% HYPERLINKS %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[colorlinks,breaklinks,
 bookmarks=false,
 pdfstartview=Fit,  % for fitting entire page; FitW just fits width
 pdfview=Fit,       % after traversing a hyperlink
 linkcolor=ChadRed,
 urlcolor=ChadGreen,
 citecolor=Black,
 hyperfootnotes=false
     ]{hyperref}
\usepackage[figure,table]{hypcap} % Correct a problem with hyperref
\urlstyle{rm} %so it doesn't use a typewriter font for url's.

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


% Fix title, sections, etc.

\let\LaTeXtitle\title
\renewcommand{\title}[1]{\LaTeXtitle{\color{ChadBlue}{\LARGE #1}}}
\renewcommand{\abstractname}{\color{ChadBlue}Abstract}
\renewcommand{\figurename}{\color{ChadBlue}Figure}
\renewcommand{\tablename}{\color{ChadBlue}Table}

\let\LaTeX@startsection\@startsection 
\renewcommand{\@startsection}[6]{\LaTeX@startsection%
{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}{\color{ChadBlue}\raggedright #6}} 

% Fix periods at end of section numbers 
%\renewcommand \thesection {\@arabic\c@section.}
%\renewcommand\thesubsection   {\thesection\@arabic\c@subsection.}
%\renewcommand\thesubsubsection{\thesubsection \@arabic\c@subsubsection.}


% Margin, Paragraph Setup
\onehalfspacing
\textheight=23cm \textwidth=17cm \topmargin=-8.5mm 
%default: \textheight=22cm \textwidth=16cm \topmargin=-6.5mm
\oddsidemargin=3mm \evensidemargin=3mm
%\setlength{\parindent}{0em} 
%\setlength{\parskip}{1.5ex plus0.5ex minus0.5ex}
%\setlength{\parsep}{0pt}
 \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}

% This is how to control linespacing using setspace
% (\singlespacing or doublespacing just call this command)
\setstretch{1.4}

%% Setting up page headers
\pagestyle{fancy}
\rhead[]{\thepage}
\lhead[\thepage]{}
\cfoot[]{} 
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\newcommand{\runningheads}[2]{
\chead[\color{ChadGreen}{\uppercase {\footnotesize #1}}]  % Author page header
{\color{ChadGreen}{\uppercase {\footnotesize #2}}}  % Short title
}

% Make hyperlinks jump more accurately
\makeatletter
\newcommand\org@hypertarget{}
\let\org@hypertarget\hypertarget
\renewcommand\hypertarget[2]{%
\Hy@raisedlink{\org@hypertarget{#1}{}}#2%
} \makeatother 


% Spacing in Tables and Figures
%\renewcommand{\tabcolsep}{1pt}   % space between columns
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5} % space between rows
\addtolength{\textfloatsep}{0pt} % space between floats and text
\addtolength{\abovecaptionskip}{0pt} % space above caption
\addtolength{\belowcaptionskip}{.15in} % space below caption

\newcommand{\spc}[0]{\vspace{.1in}}
\newcommand{\fignote}[2]{\begin{center}\parbox[c]{#1}{\footnotesize #2} \end{center}}
\newcommand{\tabnote}[2]{\begin{center}\parbox[c]{#1}{\footnotesize #2} \end{center}}
```

Dear all,
I've found the solution to the problem using chadstyle package. I've simply included the command within the subequation environment:

```
 \documentclass[10pt,twoside]{article}
 \usepackage{amsthm, etoolbox}
 .
 .
 .
 \begin{document}
 .
 .
 .
 \begin{subequations}
 \newcommand{\subequationsformat}{\theparentequation.\arabic{equation}}
  \begin{align}
    a = b \\
    c = d
  \end{align}
 \end{subequations}
 .
 .
 .
 \end{document}
```

Thanks for your time and all the suggestions!
Best, E

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please give us a minimal code which shows your subequations. We don't want to guess around here.

Comment: Dear LaRiFaRi, thanks for your quick reply. unfortunately, it's not working!

Comment: You are missing one backslash after `\label{eq:Demand_Yg} \`

Comment: What is hiding in `chadstyle.sty`?

Comment: You can see the importance of a minimal example: the information about the presence of `hyperref` was essential.

Comment: chadstyle.sty is a customized package for the font and layout design.

Comment: even putting hyperref "after" the patch, does not change anything.

Comment: The `chadstyle.sty` loads `hyperref`, so you can either do as you did, by patching the style before `hyperref`, or you could load `amsmath` patch and then load `chadstyle` afterwards.

Comment: Dear Andrew, 
i've tried both suggestions but neither worked out!

Answer (score 8):

The `amsmath` package doesn't provide an interface for changing the appearance of the equation numbers in `subequations`, but we can add one with `etoolbox`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,etoolbox}

\patchcmd\subequations
 {\theparentequation\alph{equation}}
 {\subequationsformat}
 {}{}

\newcommand{\subequationsformat}{\theparentequation.\arabic{equation}}

\begin{document}

Some text
\begin{equation}
1=1
\end{equation}
some text
\begin{subequations}
\begin{gather}
2=2\\
3=3
\end{gather}
\end{subequations}
some text
\begin{equation}
0=0
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Basically I remove the default setting passing control to a macro that's user definable. Modify `\subequationsformat` to suit your taste.

[image]

---

With `hyperref` it's slightly more complicated in that the patch has to be done *before* loading `hyperref`.

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside]{article}    
%\usepackage{chadstyle} % Loads my formatting 
\usepackage{url} 
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage{amsthm, etoolbox} 
\usepackage[title,titletoc]{appendix} 
\usepackage{pdflscape} 
\usepackage{mathtools} 
\usepackage{multirow} 
\usepackage{tabularx} 
\usepackage{placeins} % rotating Tables 
\usepackage{rotating} % coloring table columns and rows 
\usepackage{colortbl}

\patchcmd\subequations
  {\theparentequation\alph{equation}}
  {\subequationsformat}
  {}{}

\usepackage{hyperref} 

\newcolumntype{a}{>{\columncolor[gray]{.8}}c} 
\newcolumntype{b}{>{\columncolor{white}}c}

\newcommand{\subequationsformat}{\theparentequation.\arabic{equation}}


%some shortcut commands ....

\begin{document}

\section{Model}

\begin{subequations} 
\begin{align} Y_m &= X P_m^{-\sigma_x} \label{eq:Demand_Yg}\\
Y_s &= X P_s^{-\sigma_x} \label{eq:Demand_Ys} 
\end{align} 
\end{subequations}

\ref{eq:Demand_Yg}

\end{document}
```

None of your packages should be loaded after `hyperref`. Check with those you have in `chadstyle` (I can't know what's in it).

Comment: chadstyle is simply a customized package for layout and font style.

Answer (score 3):

The `subequations` environment has the format hard coded in to it, so it is not so straightforward to change.  The simplest solution is to patch the definition:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\patchcmd{\subequations}{\def\theequation{\theparentequation\alph{equation}}}%
{\def\theequation{\theparentequation.\arabic{equation}}}{}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  a = b
\end{equation}

\begin{subequations}
  \begin{align}
    c &=d \\
    e &=f
  \end{align}
\end{subequations}

\begin{align}
  g &= h\\
  i &= j
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I've tried without chadstyle package, and it works!!! Thanks to all of you!

Comment: would it be possible to add this chadstyle package, and someone takes a brief look at it to see if it's possible to embed the patch somewhere there? Thanks!

Comment: If it is not too big then you can add the code to your question.

Comment: Dear Andrew, I've added the code in my answer. Best, E