# combining cases, subequations and tags

Tags: numbering, cases, tags

I'm trying to write a set of equations in `\begin{cases}`. The i-th equation should have the tag P.i.
I can use `\tag{P}` to number the entire set as P, or, I can use `\begin{subequations}`  to number the i-th equation as 1.i. But I can't number my equations as P.1. I tried the following:

```latex
\begin{subequations}\begin{align}\label{eq:a}\tag{P}
    \begin{cases}
       a &a \tag{\ref{a}}\\
       a &a.
    \end{cases}
    \end{align}
\end{subequations}
```

but it doesn't work. Does anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  Perhaps off-topic: if there is only one cases element, what's the reason to use `align`?  `equation` would be better for that.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{subequations}\begin{align}\label{eq:a}
    \begin{cases}
       a &a \tag{P.\theequation}\\
       a &a.
    \end{cases}
    \end{align}
\end{subequations}
In \ref{eq:a}, we find blah-blah
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Ued `subnumcases` environment from `cases` for getting subnumbering for case.
Used @egreg's answer to the question: ["subequations customize arabic numbering in aligned environment"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/188333/28557) for changing the equation numbering to arabic.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,etoolbox}
\usepackage{cases}

\patchcmd\subequations
 {\theparentequation\alph{equation}}
 {\subequationsformat}
 {}{}


\newcommand{\subequationsformat}{\theparentequation.\arabic{equation}}
\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{P}
   \begin{subnumcases}{}
       a &a \label{a}\\
       b &b \label{b}
    \end{subnumcases}

\renewcommand{\theequation}{Q}
   \begin{subnumcases}{}
       c &c \label{c}\\
       d &d \label{d}
    \end{subnumcases}    

    Refer to \ref{a}, \ref{b}, \ref{c} or \ref{d}.
\end{document}
```

[image]