# Division of numbering of subequations in groups

Tags: align, numbering, subequations

I am trying to number equations of a subequations environment in subgroups (similar to the example) using the answers of [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/482575/subequations-how-to-continue-numbering-within-subequation), [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/187372/numbering-parentequation-of-subequations), and [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/188329/subequations-customize-arabic-numbering-in-aligned-environment) questions, but I could not reach to a results!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand\StepSubequations{
  \stepcounter{parentequation}
   \stepcounter{equation}
    \gdef\theparentequation{\arabic{parentequation}\Alph{equation}}
  \setcounter{equation}{0}
  \setcounter{parentequation}{1}
}
\begin{document}
    \begin{subequations}
        \begin{align}
            1   &=  1\\
            2   &=  2\\
            \StepSubequations
            3   &=  3\\% from here a new equation number
            4   &=  4\\
            5   &=  5\\
            6   &=  6\\
            \StepSubequations
            7   &=  7\\
            8   &=  8\\
            \StepSubequations
            9   &=  9\\
        \end{align}
      \end{subequations}

\end{document}
```

Expected results:

(1aA)

(1aB)

(1bA)

(1bB)

(1bC)

(1bD)

(1cA)

(1cB)

(1d)

Comment: You should probably also list what you actually get.

Comment: What exactly do you expect `\StepSubequations` to do?

Comment: You could just use `\tag{\theequation...}` for the oddball numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what you intend to do exactly and I also don't know what should happen in a `subequations` environment where you don't use `\StepSubequations` ... maybe it would be a good idea to create a new environment (as a copy of the oroginal one) that handles things as you want, so you can keep the original behaviour.

Anyways, something like this could work as starting point (but it won't suppress a single "A" as this would require to look ahead):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newcounter{equationgroup}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\subequations
    {\def\theequation{\theparentequation\alph{equation}}}
    {\def\theequation{\theparentequation\Alph{equation}}\ifmeasuring@\else\setcounter{equationgroup}{1}\fi}
    {}{}
\makeatother
\newcommand\StepSubequations{
    \stepcounter{equationgroup}
    \stepcounter{equation}
    \gdef\theparentequation{\arabic{parentequation}\alph{equationgroup}}
    \setcounter{equation}{0}
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{subequations}
        \begin{align}
            1   &=  1\\
            2   &=  2\\
            \StepSubequations
            3   &=  3\\% from here a new equation number
            4   &=  4\\
            5   &=  5\\
            6   &=  6\\
            \StepSubequations
            7   &=  7\\
            8   &=  8\\
            \StepSubequations
            9   &=  9
        \end{align}
    \end{subequations}

    \begin{subequations}
        \begin{align}
            1   &=  1\\
            2   &=  2\\
            \StepSubequations
            3   &=  3\\% from here a new equation number
            4   &=  4\\
            5   &=  5\\
            6   &=  6\\
            \StepSubequations
            7   &=  7\\
            8   &=  8\\
            \StepSubequations
            9   &=  9
        \end{align}
    \end{subequations}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

You could also place the redefinition into a command that you then need to execute (which would allow you to change between the original and the adjusted behaviour of the `subequations` environment more easily). So, maybe something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcounter{subequationsgroup}
\makeatletter
\AddToHook{env/subequations/after}{%
    \stepcounter{parentequation}%
    \gdef\theequation{\theparentequation}%
}
\newcommand{\InitializeSubequationsGroups}{%
    \ifmeasuring@\else%
        \setcounter{subequationsgroup}{\value{equation}}%
    \fi%
}
\newcommand{\StepSubequationsGroup}{%
    \ifmeasuring@\else%
        \stepcounter{subequationsgroup}%
        \setcounter{equation}{0}%
        \gdef\theequation{\theparentequation\alph{subequationsgroup}\Alph{equation}}%
    \fi%
}
\newcommand{\StepSubequationsSingle}{%
    \ifmeasuring@\else%
        \stepcounter{subequationsgroup}%
        \setcounter{equation}{0}%
        \gdef\theequation{\theparentequation\alph{subequationsgroup}}%
    \fi%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \begin{subequations}
        \begin{align}
            1   &=  1\\
            2   &=  2
        \end{align}
    \end{subequations}

    \begin{subequations}
        \begin{align}
            \InitializeSubequationsGroups
            \StepSubequationsGroup
            1   &=  1\\
            2   &=  2\\
            \StepSubequationsGroup
            3   &=  3\\% from here a new equation number
            4   &=  4\\
            5   &=  5\\
            \StepSubequationsSingle
            6   &=  6\\
            \StepSubequationsGroup
            7   &=  7\\
            8   &=  8\\
            1   &=  1\\
            2   &=  2
        \end{align}
    \end{subequations}

    \begin{subequations}
        \begin{align}
            1   &=  1\\
            2   &=  2
        \end{align}
    \end{subequations}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

My last try which should allow you to place more than one `align` inside of a `subequations` environment. You only need to take care where to place the `\EndSubequationsGroup` command if it comes last in the `subequations` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcounter{subequationsgroup}
\makeatletter
\AddToHook{env/subequations/before}{%
    \gdef\theequation{\arabic{equation}}%
}
\newcommand{\BeginSubequationsGroup}{%
    \ifmeasuring@\else%
        \setcounter{subequationsgroup}{\value{equation}}%
        \setcounter{equation}{0}%
        \stepcounter{subequationsgroup}%
        \gdef\theequation{\theparentequation\alph{subequationsgroup}\Alph{equation}}%
    \fi%
}
\newcommand{\EndSubequationsGroup}{%
    \ifmeasuring@\else%
        \setcounter{equation}{\value{subequationsgroup}}%
        \gdef\theequation{\theparentequation\alph{equation}}%
    \fi%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \begin{subequations}
        \begin{align}
            1   &=  1\\
            2   &=  2
        \end{align}
    \end{subequations}

    \begin{subequations}
        \begin{align}
            \BeginSubequationsGroup
            1   &=  1\\
            2   &=  2\\
            \EndSubequationsGroup
            3   &=  3\\
            \BeginSubequationsGroup
            4   &=  4\\
            5   &=  5\\
            \EndSubequationsGroup
            6   &=  6
        \end{align}
    \end{subequations}

    \begin{subequations}
        \begin{align}
            1   &=  1\\
            2   &=  2
        \end{align}
        
        \begin{align}
            \BeginSubequationsGroup
            1   &=  1\\
            2   &=  2
            %\EndSubequationsGroup
        \end{align}
    \end{subequations}

    \begin{subequations}
        \begin{align}
            1   &=  1\\
            \BeginSubequationsGroup
            2   &=  2\\
            3   &=  3\\
            \EndSubequationsGroup
            4   &=  4\\
            5   &=  5\\
            \BeginSubequationsGroup
            6   &=  6\\
            7   &=  7\\
            8   &=  8
        \end{align}
        
        \begin{align}
            \EndSubequationsGroup
            1   &=  1\\
            2   &=  2
        \end{align}
    \end{subequations}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Remember also that `align` executes the code twice. (use `\ifmeasuring@ ... \fi`)

Comment: @daleif Hm, but in this case, I am actually unsure where to put these ...  Do you mean `\ifmeasuring@\else\setcounter{equationgroup}{1}\fi`?

Comment: Something like that. Otherwise it is executed in the measuring stage as well.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That is what I'm was trying. But, when I don't use `\StepSubequations`, the numbers are printed in uppercase, which I expected to be compatible with the default lowercase numbering! How can I fix this?

Comment: I changed the places of `\Alph` and `\alph` with each other, but it didn't work!

Comment: @alb This is what I meant with "better create a copy of the original environment". There is no easy solution for both at once. See my edit for a possible workaround.

Comment: @JasperHabicht Thanks so much. Can I ask about your modification? I could not notice!

Comment: @alb You might need to reload the page to see the new code in my answer. I added another slight modification of the code under the original one. It does not patch but defines a new command, but for the most part, the code is the same.

Comment: Also Is there any way to print the equation without group ((1dA) in this example) without the second term (capital letter for representing the group) ((1dA)-->(1d))

Comment: I want to use two `align` environments within the `subequations`, but it continued to number as the previous group.

Comment: @JasperHabicht Thanks so much and so sorry for the broken questions.

Comment: Just `\AddToHook{env/subequations/after}{` produces error and when commenting it, it's gotten`1 = 1 (2dCa)
2 = 2 (2dCb)` for the last set of equations without error (that in your results it shows true (3a) and (3b)!

Comment: could you please solve this little problem within comments, so that there is no need for another question

Comment: @alb Well, it is not completely trivial, because the `subequations` environment already changes the regular `equation` counter. Now, in your case, the result needs to be split up, because every equation steps up the equation` counter, but you want them grouped party. I need to think again how to best do that. It is probably not too complicated, but it might be necessary to switch to another approach altogether.

Comment: @JasperHabicht Thanks again. So, do you let me to accept the answer after fixing this issue?

Comment: I think we just need to define a thing similar to `\InitializeSubequationsGroups` to put at the end of `subequations` environment to reset the numbering to the default form. Is this true?

Comment: @alb See my latest edit. Feel free to play around with it and improve it ... and it is totally up to you to upvote and/or accept the answer =)

Comment: @alb You are right more or less. My last approach does about this: it just switches between both numbering styles

Comment: Why I got error in the `\AddToHook{env/subequations/after}{` line? Also, the results are odd! such as `1 = 1 (2ca)
2 = 2 (2cb)
1 = 1 (2ccA)
2 = 2 (2ccB)
1 = 1 (3cDa)
2 = 2 (3cDbA)
3 = 3 (3cDbB)
4 = 4 (3cDc)
5 = 5 (3cDd)
6 = 6 (3cDeA)
7 = 7 (3cDeB)
8 = 8 (3cDeC)
1 = 1 (3cDf)
2 = 2 (3cDg)`. Did you exactly run your latest code version?

Comment: There is need to a `\newcommand`, in which we define a `\stepcounter` to stop `\setcounter` and put it at the end of each `subequations` environment that we define `\InitializeSubequationsGroups` at the top of it.

Comment: @alb You can be assured that I always run my code and test it with an up-to-date TeX distribution before posting here. I get the result I showed in the picture. This should run fine with TeX Live 2021 or newer (or a distribution of comparable actuality).

Comment: I had not any means, since I just exactly copied and pasted your code in the Overleaf!

Comment: Where do you think the problem is? Since I got error in the `\AddToHook{env/subequations/after}{` !. `l.5 \AddToHook
              {env/subequations/after}{%
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.`

Comment: Switch to a current TeX Live version in Overleaf. Click on "Menu" on the upper left, and then change the "TeX Live version" in the Settings section to the newest (2022 currently). Then, recompile.

Comment: @JasperHabicht It was solved. So thanks.